Why setup HSTS in absence of HTTP service
i'm wondering if its useful for my server to implement HSTS if the only available service is https ? i dont have any other open ports on my machine. So even if my browser tries to connect to http, the server wont respond. can anyone explain to me if its useful ?

Only opening the https port isn't very good practice. The better way to do it is to redirect requests from port 80 to port 443. further reading regarding HSTS
